# App unreachable after upgrading to ruby 3/rails 6.1 (demo app provided)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-3

I made a demo that tries to reproduce the issue i face. You could find it here: https://github.com/denisj/app-not-booting.

I can't find the reason why the app is not responding.
The logs for the app container look like that:

```
Attaching to test-ruby-3-rails-6_app_1
app_1  | Puma starting in single mode...
app_1  | * Puma version: 5.1.1 (ruby 3.0.0-p0) ("At Your Service")
app_1  | *  Min threads: 5
app_1  | *  Max threads: 5
app_1  | *  Environment: development
app_1  | *          PID: 1
app_1  | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
app_1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

and for the web container:

```
web_1  | 172.28.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2021:16:28:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36"
```

And few seconds later, i'm getting: 504 Gateway Time-out.

The only thing I've found is that it seems to have something to do with these 3 gems:

```
gem 'password_strength', '~> 1.1'
gem 'slack-ruby-client', '~> 0.15'
gem 'asset_sync', '~> 2.12'
```

When I disable one, the app is working (I mean I hope so).

Comment: are there any other logs in the app you could look at?

Comment: I don't really know about. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: "Fixed it" by changing one of the gems that were problematic.

Comment: @den which gem was it?

Comment: I just change the gem password_strength by strong_password (with a minor fix for ruby 3.0). I'm not sure that this gem was problematic, but the 3 used at the same time was posing an issue.